# WM_PAINT not being called after window is created

Tags: c++, winapi

I've been playing around with the Windows api for uni, but I cant get the window messages to call WM_PAINT after the inital creation. It calls it when the window is created but not after.

All Other messages get called! Just cant get the WM_PAINT to be called.

This is part of a game lib we have to make using the Windows api, (the goal is to learn abit of the windows api, rather than the intricacies of making game libs).

From what I gather the UpdateWindow(handle) command calls inititates the WM_PAINT message, but no matter where I put this command (currently in the game loop) I cant get it to call the message.

There's a lot of code, so I've trimmed it a little.

I know I have multiple WM_PAINT cases, they are a result of trying to make sure its getting through.

Window Creation
        HWND hwnd;

```
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_APPWINDOW | WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE,
        L"FirstWindowClass",
        L"Mootlib",
        WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        m_screenWidth,
        m_screenHeight,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        WindowsUtilities::windowInstance(),
        NULL);
```

Register the Window

```
    WNDCLASSEX  wcex;                                   

    wcex.cbSize        = sizeof (wcex);             
    wcex.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;       
    wcex.lpfnWndProc   = windowProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra    = 0;                             
    wcex.cbWndExtra    = 0;                             
    wcex.hInstance     = WindowsUtilities::windowInstance();
    wcex.hIcon         = 0; 
    wcex.hCursor       = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);  

    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) (COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName  = NULL;                          
    wcex.lpszClassName = L"FirstWindowClass";               
    wcex.hIconSm       = 0; 

    RegisterClassEx (&wcex);
```

Winproc

```
    LRESULT CALLBACK windowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        LONG_PTR lptr = GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA);

        switch(message)
        {
        case(WM_PAINT):
            int f = 3;
        }

        if (lptr)
        {
            Window* obj = reinterpret_cast<Window*>(lptr);
            return obj->handleWindowsMessages(message, wParam, lParam);
        }
        else
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
```

Internal command

```
LRESULT Window::handleWindowsMessages(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    std::wstring szHello = L"Hello, world!";
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;

    switch(message)
    {
    case(WM_PAINT):
        hdc = BeginPaint(m_handle, &ps); 
        TextOut(hdc, 0, 0, L"Hello, Windows!", 15); 
        EndPaint(m_handle, &ps); 
        return 0; 

    case(WM_CLOSE):
        quitGame();
        return 0;

    // Move Me!!!
    case(WM_KEYDOWN):
    case(WM_LBUTTONDOWN):
    case(WM_RBUTTONDOWN):
        inputManager().addButtonEvent(reinterpret_cast<int&>(wParam), BUTTON_DOWN);
        return 0;

    // Move Me!!!
    case(WM_KEYUP):
    case(WM_LBUTTONUP):
    case(WM_RBUTTONUP):
        inputManager().addButtonEvent(reinterpret_cast<int&>(wParam), BUTTON_UP);
        return 0;   
    }

    return DefWindowProc(handle(), message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Game Loop

```
        while(IsWindowVisible(handle()))
        {
            UpdateWindow(handle());
            WindowsUtilities::processMessages();

            draw();
            update();

            inputManager().update();
            inputManager().clearButtonUpEvents(); // this should be in the input update()
        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: First thought, from the title, did you set WS_VISIBLE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I really don't like your game loop as its not at all obvious where the windows message pump is.

Somewhere along the line you need to call `PeekMessage()` or `GetMessage()` and `TranslateMessage()` & `DispatchMessage()` on any messages retrieved. Lots of people unfamiliar with windows will filter the messages, either in a range, or for a window: don't - always pump all messages for all windows on the current thread.

Then you need to call [InvalidateRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145002%28VS.85%29.aspx) to mark the areas of the window you want repainted. Games will want to pass FALSE as getting the background painted is just a waste of time when youre painting the entire scene in `WM_PAINT`.

[RedrawWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162911%28VS.85%29.aspx) is useful for a game if you just want to mark an entire part of the window dirty and repaint it in one step. The advantage of [InvalidateRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145002%28VS.85%29.aspx) is that it just adds the rectangle to a dirty region, so if your game consists of just a few small 'active' sprites, as each sprite animates you can mark just the corresponding rect dirty, and windows will collect the dirty rects and paint them in a batch when next you call `UpdateWindow`, or let the message loop generate a `WM_PAINT` message.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snippet from the canonical Windows code, auto-generated when you create a new Win32 project in Visual Studio:

```
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   HWND hWnd;

   hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

   hWnd = CreateWindow(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}
```

Note what's missing in yours: you forgot to call ShowWindow().

Answer (score 0):

If you want `WM_PAINT` to be called, you can use `RedrawWindow` or `InvalidateRect`.

Answer (score -1):

MSDN states:

> The UpdateWindow function updates the
>   client area of the specified window by
>   sending a WM_PAINT message to the
>   window **if the window's update region
>   is not empty**.

Your issue is that you haven't set an update region.

You could just do:

```
SendMessage( handle(), WM_PAINT, 0, 0 );
```